# More on recommendable caching practices?

Tags: 7, caching

Having read this [Q & A](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17196/caching-techniques-suggestions-best-practices), I feel like asking some more, perhaps very basic, questions anyway.

I'm just about to deploy a taxonomy- and Views-intensive site, and I'm wondering about the best cache practices with regards to Drupal and Views configuration.

Needless to say that all my caches are turned off for the purpose of reliable development, but for the sake of speed and server efficiency, some caching should be enabled when the site goes live.

The following questions come to my mind:

1. Should the `Expiration of cached pages` and `Minimum cache lifetime`
   settings depend on the frequency of adding content to the site?
2. Is it possible to broadly define types of Views that should have their cache
   turned on? and which should not?
3. If you were to turn the cache on, where would you do that: on the production site, or the development one before
   deployment?
4. Has anybody developed a comfortable operational pattern
   using a staging and production sites using Deploy module, with
   regards to cache? If so, what practice do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is great info on views caching on this [Q&A](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22724/are-views-cached-through-the-core-caching-mechanisms-or-should-i-be-setting-the). It should answer your questions 1-3.
The 4th should probably be asked as a separate question.